# Convert the eastimate $\|u\|_{L^q(\Bbb{R}^n)}\le \|(\Delta +z) u\|_{L^p}$ into multiplier form

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, sobolev-spaces, harmonic-analysis

I was trying to prove the following estimate

$$ \|u\|_{L^q(\Bbb{R}^n)}\le \|(\Delta +z) u\|_{L^p(\Bbb{R}^n)} \tag{*}$$
For all $z\in \Bbb{C}$,all $u\in C^\infty_c(\Bbb{R}^n)$,with $n\ge 3,$ and $\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{q} = \frac{2}{n}$ and $\frac{n+1}{2n} <\frac{1}{p}<\frac{n+3}{2n}$.

Our professor told us we can find the solution in Koenig, Ruiz, Sogge 1987 paper [here](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/duke-mathematical-journal/volume-55/issue-2/Uniform-Sobolev-inequalities-and-unique-continuation-for-second-order-constant/10.1215/S0012-7094-87-05518-9.short).

I  found this problem is related to theorem 2.3 in the paper.

**my question is why estimate (*) is equivalent to the multiplier form problem:**

$$\|\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left(\frac{\hat{u}}{-4\pi^2|\xi|^2+z}\right)\|_q \le\|u\|_p$$

I found typically,we need to convert the problem into muliplier form in order to apply Stein's interpolation theorem.

Comment: Replace $u$ in the second estimate by $(-\Delta +z)u$ and immediately recover the first inequality (I assume here that it should be $\vert \xi\vert^2$ instead of $\vert \xi\vert_2$).

Comment: Oh thank you I got it.